# I want to make a parent nav link sidebar active when its child is active (current page)

Tags: javascript, html

Here's my code:
I want it in a way that when i click on a child link, it becomes active and the parent link is active too. I utilize the css class .active for my active classes for both the main and sub-menu.

The below JS snippet works but only for the menus without sub-menus

```js
$(document).ready(function($) {
  var url = window.location.href;
  var activePage = url;
  $('.menu li a').each(function() {
    var linkPage = this.href;

    if (activePage == linkPage) {
      $(this).closest("li").addClass("active");
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="menu">
  <ul class="list">
    <li class="header">MAIN NAVIGATION</li>
    <li class="">
      <a href="index.php">
        <i class="material-icons">home</i>
        <span>Dashboard</span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="sell.php">
        <i class="material-icons">receipt</i>
        <span>Sell</span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">
        <i class="material-icons">show_chart</i>
        <span>Reporting</span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="menu-toggle">
        <i class="material-icons">apps</i>
        <span>Products</span>
      </a>
      <ul class="ml-menu">
        <li>
          <a href="add-product.php">Add Product</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="products.php">All Products</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="add-category.php">Add Category</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="categories.php">All Categories</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<!-- #Menu -->
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. What have you tried so far?

Comment: This so far works but only on the menus that have no sub-menus 'code' $(document).ready(function ($) {
  var url = window.location.href;
  var activePage = url;
  $('.menu li a').each(function () {
   var linkPage = this.href;

   if (activePage == linkPage) {
    $(this).closest("li").addClass("active");
   }
  });
 }); 'code'

Comment: Can you add it to the question?

Comment: I have added the JS snippet

Answer (score 0):

Implement an on `mousedown` event listener for your anchor tags, passing in the id for each anchor tag and use the `parentElement` property to get the element's parent.

```
document.getElementById("myLI").parentElement.nodeName;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this JS code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('a').click(function () {
            //removing the previous selected menu state
            $('.menu').find('li.active').removeClass('active');
            //adding the state for this parent menu
            $(this).parents("li").addClass('active');

        });
    });
```

And the css for Active link:

```
.active > a {
    color:red;
}
```

hope it helps...

Comment: Thank you. However what this does is, it highlights the parent on click but whenever I click on it's child, the child link doesn't highlight as active. I have set all the css styling perfectly, what am trying to do, is make the current link have the active class and if it's a child link, input the active class on both the child and the parent.

Comment: @ItsyBitsyFisty : add your css in your question

Comment: @ItsyBitsyFisty: strange. I tested and it's working.. I just tried on the last navigation part at https://codepen.io/nilesh-kumar/pen/bOYvVy

Comment: It doesn't work on my end... See, the initial js code I posted does half the job but only on the main nav, for those that have children it doesn't inject the class '.active'. I need help in ensuring that happens for both the parent and the child.